# как контролировать подключение

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Я подключаю через iframe к своему сайту свою игру,она работает по ссылки и получается ,что её может подключить любой желающий к своему ресурсу,есть ли способ как то контролировать чтобы её мог подключить только я,а другим сторонним ресурсам сервер не отвечал?

```
 <iframe src="https://"  width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" >
    
 </iframe>
```

Comment: можно установить заголовок [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) либо на клиенте проверять, что загружено в iframe и проверять домен родительского окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контролировать с вашего ресурса не получится, это нужно делать там где находится сама игра. Вполне можно сделать, чтобы работала только для определенных айпи, либо какую-нибудь авторизацию добавить